# suppress expansion in macro call

Tags: macros, luatex, expansion

What I would like is to suppress the expansion of the group as a parameter to a macro so that it can be expanded later. For example we want to pass the paramater unmodified as a string to lua or to a file.

Let us suppose we have a macro `\foo` which accepts a parameter.

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \directlua{foo([[#1]]}%
  }
```

if we call it as:
`\foo{\bar{abc}}` the `\bar` gets expanded before `\foo` gets to see it.
Of course we can manually suppress the expansion with `\foo{\noexpand\bar{abc}}`, but can it be done automatically?

Comment: I'd say `\directlua{foo([[\unexpanded{#1}]])}`

Answer (score 4):

Without a full example to test this is untested but I would assume that you could go

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \directlua{foo([[\unexpanded{#1}]]}%
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really answer your question, but I think you are thinking about expansion wrong.

> if we call it as: \foo{\bar{abc}} the \bar gets expanded before \foo
>   gets to see it.

The argument to `\foo` is not expanded before `\foo` gets to see it. It is expanded inside `\foo`. Consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\foo#1{\def\bar{a}#1}
\begin{document}
\def\bar{x}
\foo{\bar}
\end{document}
```

If you want to expand `\bar` before `\foo` get to see it you need an `\expandafter`: `\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\bar{abc}}`

Comment: You actually want two of them: `\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\bar{abc}}`.  What you wrote only expands the `{`, which has no effect.